# How to insert images through Open Gl in ios?

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I have just started learning OpenGl, i have read about Rendering and texture image. If anyone can provide a simple example to insert image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL itself doesn’t provide API to generate a texture from image file. We had to read image file and convert it to bitmap data to use texture in OpenGL before, but `GLKTextureLoader` class in `GLKit` enables us generating texture from image automatically.

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mushroom" ofType:@"png"];
GLKTextureInfo* textureInfo =
  [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:nil error:nil];
if (textureInfo) {
    NSLog(@"Texture loaded successfully. name = %d size = (%d x %d)",
          textureInfo.name, textureInfo.width, textureInfo.height);
}
```

return value of `textureWithContentsOfFile:options:error:` method is an instance of `GLKTextureInfo` class. A `GLKTextureInfo` object contains information about a texture such as width, height… There is a property named ‘name’ (documented as ‘glName’ and it should be misprint). We use value in this property to specify texture in `GLKBaseEffect` (Will be described later)

`GLKTextureLoader` is a class for loading textures, so we should release texture by our self. Call `glDeleteTextures` with value of ‘name’ property in `GLKTextureInfo` object.

Found this nice discussion in a blog. Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: Please share the blog, i am new to Open Gl thanks for the answer.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3664/opengl-tutorial-for-ios-opengl-es-2-0

Its  a good tutorial. If my answer helped then you should accept my answer.